# Rails model has and belongs to many list types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, User and Product

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now I want to make three lists for each user, products they've checked out recently, products that are in their shopping cart and products which they have bought. How do I make a distinction between these relations? Could I add some sort of type column to the relation table? And how could I then later check this type?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord or something else ? If so, please check first [rails association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 1):

If you and to add other columns to the relation table perhaps you should consider using has_many on both User and Products, then you can add your columns on Cart

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carts
  has_many :products, through: :carts
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carts
  has_many :users, through: :carts
end
```